# Does calling a method on a value type result in boxing in .NET?

Tags: .net, boxing, value-type

I was just participating in Stack Overflow question *[Is everything in .NET an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436211/is-everything-in-c-an-object)*.

And one poster (in comments of accepted answer) seemed to think that performing a method call on a value type resulted in boxing. He pointed me to *[Boxing and Unboxing (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk(VS.80).aspx)* which doesn't exactly specify the use case we're describing.

I'm not one to trust a single source, so I just wanted to get further feedback on the question. My intuition is that there is no boxing but my intuition does suck. :D

To further elaborate:

The example I used was:

```
int x = 5;
string s = x.ToString(); // Boxing??
```

Boxing does *not* occur if the struct in question overrides the method inherited from the object as the accepted answer here states.

However if the struct doesn't override the method, a "constrain" [CIL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language) command is executed prior to a callvirt. According to the documentation, *[OpCodes.Constrained Field](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.constrained.aspx)*, **this results in boxing**:

> If thisType is a value type and
>   thisType does not implement method
>   then ptr is dereferenced, boxed, and
>   passed as the 'this' pointer to the
>   callvirt method instruction.

Comment: And the reason here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359856/why-does-implicitly-calling-tostring-on-a-value-type-cause-a-box-instruction

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here's the IL for your code:

```
L_0001: ldc.i4.5      // get a 5 on the stack
L_0002: stloc.0       // store into x
L_0003: ldloca.s x    // get the address of x on the stack
L_0005: call instance string [mscorlib]System.Int32::ToString()  // ToString
L_000a: stloc.1       // store in s
```

So the answer in this case is no.

Comment: An important note here is that the ToString method is not being called against the value of x, but the address of x. Notice the ldloc**a** instruction.

Answer (score 12):

In the case you have given the answer is no, as plinth pointed out.

However, it will if you call a method through an interface pointer.

Consider the code:

```
interface IZot
{
    int F();
}

struct Zot : IZot
{
    public int F()
    {
        return 123;
    }
}
```

Then

```
Zot z = new Zot();
z.F();
```

Does **not** result in boxing:

```
.locals init (
    [0] valuetype ConsoleApplication1.Zot z)
L_0000: nop 
L_0001: ldloca.s z
L_0003: initobj ConsoleApplication1.Zot
L_0009: ldloca.s z
L_000b: call instance int32 ConsoleApplication1.Zot::F()
L_0010: pop 
L_0011: ret
```

However, this does:

```
IZot z = new Zot();
z.F();

   .locals init (
        [0] class ConsoleApplication1.IZot z,
        [1] valuetype ConsoleApplication1.Zot CS$0$0000)
    L_0000: nop 
    L_0001: ldloca.s CS$0$0000
    L_0003: initobj ConsoleApplication1.Zot
    L_0009: ldloc.1 
    L_000a: box ConsoleApplication1.Zot
    L_000f: stloc.0 
    L_0010: ldloc.0 
    L_0011: callvirt instance int32 ConsoleApplication1.IZot::F()
    L_0016: pop
```

Answer (score 7):

@[ggf31316](https://stackoverflow.com/users/38561/ggf31416)

> "I believe that calling ToString,
>   Equals and Gethashcode result in
>   boxing if the structure does not
>   override the methods."

I have checked ToString for you. Int32 does override ToString, so I made a struct that doesn't. I used [.NET Reflector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Reflector) to ensure that the struct wasn't somehow magically overriding ToString(), and it wasn't.

So the code was like this:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication29
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MyStruct ms = new MyStruct(5);
            string s = ms.ToString();
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }
    }

    struct MyStruct
    {
        private int m_SomeInt;

        public MyStruct(int someInt)
        {
            m_SomeInt = someInt;
        }

        public int SomeInt
        {
            get
            {
                return m_SomeInt;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the MSIL (via [ILDASM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language#Generation)) for the Main method is this:

```
  IL_0000:  ldloca.s   ms
  IL_0002:  ldc.i4.5
  IL_0003:  call       instance void ConsoleApplication29.MyStruct::.ctor(int32)
  IL_0008:  ldloca.s   ms
  IL_000a:  constrained. ConsoleApplication29.MyStruct
  IL_0010:  callvirt   instance string [mscorlib]System.Object::ToString()
  IL_0015:  stloc.1
  IL_0016:  ldloc.1
  IL_0017:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
  IL_001c:  ret
```

Now, despite no boxing call taking place, if you check [the documentation about a constrained + a call virt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.constrained.aspx), you will find it states that boxing DOES take place. oOo

Quote:

> If thisType is a value type and
>   thisType does not implement method
>   then ptr is dereferenced, boxed, and
>   passed as the 'this' pointer to the
>   callvirt  method instruction.

Answer (score 4):

I believe that calling ToString, Equals and Gethashcode result in boxing if the structure does not override the methods.