# How to reverse this object.ToString for value types rule in Resharper?

Tags: c#, resharper

According to a question asked and answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359856/why-does-implicitly-calling-tostring-on-a-value-type-cause-a-box-instruction) not calling ToString on methods like WriteLine, String.Format etc introduces boxing for value types as the methods are accepting objects.

Resharper though considers the code redundant. I on the other hand wish not only to remove the rule but also to reverse the rule to suggest the addition of ToString on value types to remove the unneeded boxing. 
How can I do that?

**EDIT Clarification**
In String.Format accepts objects and not value types, thus when calling String.Format without ToString on a value type boxing occurs in order for the argument to match the expected argument in String.Format. Which is completely unneeded and reduces (even if it is slightly) the performance of the call.

Comment: Do you want Resharper not to mark `ToString()` as redundant for value types?

Comment: No I want resharper to suggest putting to string for value types

Comment: So no boxing would happen

Comment: But when you do `Console.WriteLine(someInt);` the `ToSrting()` method is implicitly called, so the previous line of code will be equal to `Console.WriteLine(someInt.ToString());` When you write you code as second case you simply will call `ToString()` explicitly.

Comment: @Roma Not on String.Format though and String interpolation

Comment: there is no option in resharper to force to suggest a warning for using `ToString()` with value types. But you can write your own plugin for resharper.

Comment: @Roma So There is no way to write a custom rule? Are you sure about this? I know you can do it with naming conventions, writing custom naming rules.

Comment: I am not sure, I googled and didn't find another way. Maybe you will find a better way.