# GetType on Nullable Boolean

Tags: c#, null, boolean

I was looking into nullable bools when I found this article on Microsoft MSDN

[How to: Identify a Nullable Type (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366789.aspx)

> You can use the C# typeof operator to create a Type object that represents a Nullable type.

So I tried checking with a nullable bool:

```
Console.Write(typeof(bool?)); //System.Nullable`1[System.Boolean]
```

The article on MSDN says

> You can also use the classes and methods of the System.Reflection namespace to generate Type objects that represent Nullable types. However, if you try to obtain type information from Nullable variables at runtime by using the GetType method or the is operator, the result is a Type object that represents the underlying type, not the Nullable type itself.
>
> Calling GetType on a Nullable type causes a boxing operation to be performed when the type is implicitly converted to Object. **Therefore GetType always returns a Type object that represents the underlying type, not the Nullable type.**

If this is true I expect to get the same result from `.GetType()` whether I use a nullable bool or a regular bool. But this is not what happens:

```
    bool a = new bool();
    Console.Write(a.GetType()); //Prints System.Boolean

    bool? b = new bool?();
    Console.Write(b.GetType()); //Exception!
```

The exception that occured:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in BoolTest.exe
>
> Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

But the object reference is set to an instance of an object. What could be the cause of this error?

Comment: `T?` is a special type in .NET and there are many oddities involving them, all of which have been beaten to death on SO. You can search about it. Another one is, even though `b.GetType()` fails, `b.ToString()` doesn't. It has a reason in .NET but odd choice still. Another one is, had `b` been `bool? b = true`, then `b.GetType()` gives `System.Boolean` and not `System.Nullable<Boolean>`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're calling `GetType` on a `NULL` Reference (The result of boxing a Nullable Type with No Value).

`bool? b = new bool?();` is equivalent to `bool? b = null;`

Try this to get the correct result:

```
bool? b = new bool?(false);
Console.Write(b.GetType()); // System.Boolean
```

The documentation means that if you call `GetType()` successfully on a `Nullable` object that has value (Not Null). You get the Underlying type which is `System.Boolean`. But you can't call any method using a `NULL` reference and this is a general rule that applying to any reference type.

To clear the equivalence point between `= null` and `new bool?()`, check this [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/MyQFSs). Both generates the same IL:

```
IL_0001:  ldloca.s   V_0
IL_0003:  initobj    valuetype [mscorlib]System.Nullable`1<bool>
```

and

```
IL_0009:  ldloca.s   V_1
IL_000b:  initobj    valuetype [mscorlib]System.Nullable`1<bool>
```

Comment: _"bool? b = new bool?(); is equivelant to bool? b = null;"_ - no, it isn't. `new` never returns `null`. Furthermore, `bool? b = new bool?(false)` is something entirely different than `bool? b = new bool?()`. The former does hold a bool value, the latter doesn't.

Comment: @CodeCaster I didn't say `bool? b = new bool?(false)` is equivalent to `bool? b = new bool?()`. I was trying to give the OP an example that prints the underlying type as stated in the docs. As for you first statement, here is the proof: https://dotnetfiddle.net/MyQFSs (Check the generated IL)

Comment: I stand corrected, both indeed get compiled to `initobj`. So while `Nullable<T>` is a struct, you can initialize it with `null`, but then it actually isn't null, because `bool? foo = null; foo.HasValue` doesn't throw. Nullables are weird.

Answer (score 7):

Your actual question seems to be:

> By initializing a `Nullable<T>` to its default value using its default constructor, for example `bool? b = new bool?();`, why does accessing `b`'s members such as `GetType()` throw a `NullReferenceException`? Doesn't `new` always return a value, so `b` can't really be `null`?

Well, yes and no. `Nullable<T>` is kind of special. From the C# specs:

> **4.1.10 Nullable types**
>
> [...]
>
> An instance of a nullable type T? has two public read-only properties:
>
> - A HasValue property of type bool
> - A Value property of type T
>
> An instance for which HasValue is true is said to be non-null. A non-null instance contains a known value and Value returns that value.
>   **An instance for which HasValue is false is said to be null. A null instance has an undefined value**. Attempting to read the Value of a null instance causes a System.InvalidOperationException to be thrown.

So yes, `bool? b = new bool?();` does return an instance: one you only can call `HasValue` on. Since it returns `false`, you can't do much else with that instance.

Then the next relevant section:

> **4.3.1 Boxing conversions**
>
> Boxing a value of a nullable-type produces a null reference if it is the null value (HasValue is false)

This is also explained in  [MSDN: Boxing Nullable Types (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228597.aspx):

> Objects based on nullable types are only boxed if the object is non-null. If HasValue is false, **the object reference is assigned to null instead of boxing**.

Somewhat further into the specs:

> **11.3.5 Boxing and unboxing**
>
> When a struct type overrides a virtual method inherited from System.Object (such as Equals, GetHashCode, or ToString), invocation of the virtual method through an instance of the struct type does not cause boxing to occur.

`GetType()` is not overridden by `Nullable<T>`, so boxing will occur. When you call `GetType()` or any non-overridden method on a struct, the struct will be boxed to an object before calling that method. In the case of a null `Nullable<T>`, the result of that boxing operation will be `(object)null`. Hence the exception.

See also [Does calling a method on a value type result in boxing in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436363/does-calling-a-method-on-a-value-type-result-in-boxing-in-net).

---

So, to answer your question:

- `b` is **not** null, it holds a `Nullable<bool>` with a `HasValue` indicating `false`.
- Calling the non-overridden `GetType()` method on it, causes the `Nullable<bool>` struct to be boxed in order to access the underlying method `object.GetType()`.
- This boxing operation actually doesn't box, but simply returns `(object)null`.
- In the end, you're calling `((object)null).GetType()`, which throws the `NullReferenceException` you encounter.

---

If you're actually looking for a piece of code that can return the type of any variable, even a null `Nullable<T>`, use something like this:

```
Type GetType<T>(T obj) 
{ 
    return typeof(T); 
}
```

Which you can then call like this:

```
Console.WriteLine(GetType(b));
```