# GetType of nullable int returns same as GetType of int

Tags: c#, expression, nullable, func

I have a function that gets an expression as parameter. The type of the expression is `Func<int?>`. But when the expression is evaluated, the nullable int is unpacked.

See following Code:

```
using System;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var asd = new Asd() { Id = 1 };
        Do(() => asd.Id);
        Console.Read();
    }

    private static void Do<T>(Expression<Func<T>> expr)
    {
        var tType = typeof(T);
        var type = expr.Compile()().GetType();
        Console.Write($"T = {tType.Name}, obj type = {type.Name}");
    }

    class Asd
    {
        public int? Id { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The console shows following output:

```
T = Nullable`1, obj type = Int32
```

Why does this happen and how can I avoid this?
Unfortunately I can not provide a dotnetfiddle because this code does not run in dotnetfiddle. maybe because of the expressions.

**//Edit:**

To make it clear: I need the property **Id** to be of type `int?` and I need to compile and execute the function. The problem here occurs in a bigger pice of code. This code is only the minimum required set of code to have a runnable example.

Best regards

**//Edit 2:**

It turned out that my small example produces errors, too, which let me think that it shows my actual problem. But of course it does not.
I used `GetType()` to show you that the functions return value is not of type `Nullable<int>` but of `int`. According to the links provided in the comments, GetType() induces a unboxing of the nullable and thus returns the underlying type.

My real problem was another one that maybe has similar reasons.
I used `var valueExpr = Expression.Constant(valueFromImport);` to create a constant expression with the nullable value `int? valueFromImport = ...`. Later on I setup an expression to assign the constant to a nullable property. That failes with an exception:

```
System.ArgumentException: "Expression of type 'System.Int32' cannot be used for assignment to type 'System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]'"
```

The problem was, that `Expression.Constant` also seems to unbox the nullable value. When I use  `var valueExpr = Expression.Constant(valueFromImport, typeof(T));` everything works as expected.

Comment: You are compiling it then calling it. Remove one set of `()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GetType on Nullable Boolean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38551698/gettype-on-nullable-boolean)

Comment: Just replace `Console.Write($"T = {tType.Name}, obj type = {type.Name}");` with `Console.Write($"T = {tType}, obj type = {type.Name}");` and you will get your information about the type of the generic argument (hint: you get `Nullable'1[Int32]` rather than just `Nullable'1`).

Comment: This code works fine in .NET Fiddle if you fix it by removing ``interpolated string`` and unnecessary ``()``

Comment: @Crowcoder that was intended. I need to get the result of the expression`s underlying function. See my edit

Comment: @JosefBiehler OK, but the type of the expression and the type of the result is not the same. What are you expecting?

Comment: `The problem is that the console shows int32 for the function's result.` Read the link I gave you. Read the question particularly. Read, in particular, the MSDN quote in it. The bit in **bold**. I suspect it may relate to, and explain, your situation.

Comment: @mjwills thanks . Sry for rejecting your comment. I was too fixed on solving the problem that occured in my original code that I ignored the GetType() problem. Again what learned. The GetType() behaviour hides my actual problem. What a bad luck to find an minimum runnable example that also produces errors. But thanks to your hint to GetType() I was able to solve it on my own. I will describe it in my initial post for future researches. maybe someone other needs it, too.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "int is unpacked"? The result of the expressio still is of type `int?`, but you can't get it via reflection, which is the expected behavior. Citing [msdn for Nullables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/nullable-types/how-to-identify-a-nullable-type):

> Calling GetType on a Nullable type causes a boxing operation to be performed when the type is implicitly converted to Object. Therefore GetType always returns a Type object that represents the underlying type, not the Nullable type.

Either way, what is your main problem? The result is of the correct type and you can still get it with `typeof(T)`. The result of `GetType` shouldn't get in your way.