# C# get nullable datetime ToString format method with params to set Expression.Call

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to build dynamically build an expression LINQ function, when I do string comparison for datetime I get `ToString` method with format argument:

```cs
else if (member.Type == typeof(DateTime))
{
    var toString = typeof(DateTime).GetMethod("ToString", new Type[] { typeof(string) });
    member = Expression.Call(member, toString, Expression.Constant("yyyyMMdd"));
}
```

I need to get `ToString` format method of `DateTime?`.

Comment: `DateTime?` === `Nullable<DateTime>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend building an expression like;

```cs
Expression<Func<T?, string>> expr = d => d.HasValue ? d.Value.ToString("...") : null;
```

For example;

```cs
        private static Dictionary<Type,string> Formats = ...

        private Expression ToString(Expression value)
        {
            if (value.Type.IsGenericType && value.Type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>))
            {
                return Expression.Condition(
                    Expression.Property(value, "HasValue"),
                    ToString(Expression.Property(value, "Value")),
                    Expression.Constant(null, typeof(string))
                );
            }
            var toString = value.Type.GetMethod("ToString", new Type[] { typeof(string) });
            return Expression.Call(value, toString, Expression.Constant(Formats[value.Type]));
        }
```

Comment: This is the code a was looking for. Thanks, it works!

Comment: Does this work for DateTimeOffset?

Answer (score 0):

Here a small example with a `DateTime?`. You have to handle the case where to value is null, makes no sense to call `ToString()` in this case.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DateTime? dateTime = ...;
        string result = "";

        if (dateTime.HasValue)
        {
            ConstantExpression constant = Expression.Constant(dateTime);
            MethodInfo? toString = typeof(DateTime).GetMethod("ToString", new[] { typeof(string) });
            MethodCallExpression call = Expression.Call(constant, toString, Expression.Constant("yyyyMMdd"));

            result = Expression.Lambda<Func<string>>(call).Compile()();
        }

        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what the relevance of the code block you pasted there is; is it you saying "this works for DateTime but not DateTime?" or is it you saying "this is what I'm trying to do with my DateTime?" ?

As such, I cant really tell you what to do but I can point out a couple of problems you'll encounter:

- If your `member.Type` is returning a type of a `DateTime?` it won't ever be equal to a `typeof(DateTime)` because they are different types. Additionally, I'm not sure how `member.Type` comes to have a value but if it's via `someInstance.GetType()` you should bear in mind that calling `GetType()` on a null nullable throws a null reference exception. See [GetType on Nullable Boolean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38551698/gettype-on-nullable-boolean) for a lengthy discourse on this
- a `DateTime?` doesn't have a `ToString(string format)` overload. You might need to implement something that checks if `member.Type` is a nullable type and then do your work with the nullable's .Value instead..