# Declare the variable closer to where it is defined? C# IL code is not the same

Tags: c#, variables, optimization

In C#, I was wondering if we should declare the varbile clsoer to where it is used or not and yes there are multiple questions asked this same question. But still I have doubts!

with a sample code like this I tried:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for(int i= 0; i<=1000; i++)
    {
        int myVariable = 12;
        myVariable = i;
    }
}
```

the other time I moved the line of code for int myVariable = 12; to right before the for loop. And these are what I get in ILDASM,  previsouds questions and answers say that C# created the same code, but here we see that not really! So what is going on? Finally is it a good practice or not? - with C# compiler -

**Variable inside:**

```
.method private hidebysig instance void  button1_Click(object sender,
                                                       class [mscorlib]System.EventArgs e) cil managed
{
  // Code size       32 (0x20)
  .maxstack  2
  .locals init ([0] int32 i,
           [1] int32 myVariable,
           [2] bool CS$4$0000)
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  ldc.i4.0
  IL_0002:  stloc.0
  IL_0003:  br.s       IL_0010
  IL_0005:  nop
  IL_0006:  ldc.i4.s   12
  IL_0008:  stloc.1
  IL_0009:  ldloc.0
  IL_000a:  stloc.1
  IL_000b:  nop
  IL_000c:  ldloc.0
  IL_000d:  ldc.i4.1
  IL_000e:  add
  IL_000f:  stloc.0
  IL_0010:  ldloc.0
  IL_0011:  ldc.i4     0x3e8
  IL_0016:  cgt
  IL_0018:  ldc.i4.0
  IL_0019:  ceq
  IL_001b:  stloc.2
  IL_001c:  ldloc.2
  IL_001d:  brtrue.s   IL_0005
  IL_001f:  ret
} /
```

/ end of method Form1::button1_Click

**Variable outside of the for loop:**

```
.method private hidebysig instance void  button1_Click(object sender,
                                                       class [mscorlib]System.EventArgs e) cil managed
{
  // Code size       32 (0x20)
  .maxstack  2
  .locals init ([0] int32 myVariable,
           [1] int32 i,
           [2] bool CS$4$0000)
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  ldc.i4.s   12
  IL_0003:  stloc.0
  IL_0004:  ldc.i4.0
  IL_0005:  stloc.1
  IL_0006:  br.s       IL_0010
  IL_0008:  nop
  IL_0009:  ldloc.1
  IL_000a:  stloc.0
  IL_000b:  nop
  IL_000c:  ldloc.1
  IL_000d:  ldc.i4.1
  IL_000e:  add
  IL_000f:  stloc.1
  IL_0010:  ldloc.1
  IL_0011:  ldc.i4     0x3e8
  IL_0016:  cgt
  IL_0018:  ldc.i4.0
  IL_0019:  ceq
  IL_001b:  stloc.2
  IL_001c:  ldloc.2
  IL_001d:  brtrue.s   IL_0008
  IL_001f:  ret
} // end of method Form1::button1_Click
```

Comment: Make sure you compile in Release mode with optimizations enabled.

Comment: @MichaelLiu Wow! that made a lot lot of difference! The IL code in Release mode looks way different and NOW both codes look exactly the same. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Good practice **depends** entirely on what your *needs* are!  If you need a different variable, each iteration of the loop, you create it inside the loop, else you should put it outside.