# Value types inherit from System.Object...why?

Tags: c#, object, types

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Is everything in .NET an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436211/is-everything-in-net-an-object)
>   [How do ValueTypes derive from Object (ReferenceType) and still be ValueTypes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1682231/how-do-valuetypes-derive-from-object-referencetype-and-still-be-valuetypes)

Hi,
I just do not get it. System.Object is (I think) reference type but all data types in .NET inherit from it. Also value types do as well. I do not understand it - value type has its value on the stack but its inherited from Object?
Hope anyone could help me to understand

Comment: Possible duplicate....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/436211/is-everything-in-net-an-object/436246

Comment: All your type are belong to us!

Answer (score 12):

You are correct that, while Object is a reference type, value types do inherit from it *implicitly*, as stated on msdn's reference for [Value Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) (according to the reference, they technically inherit from the [ValueType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.valuetype.aspx) class, which in turn inherits from Object.

C# made a special case for this so value types can benefit from Object's methods (like ToString) and properties. Also, this way, you can treat value types just like other reference types--nothing stopping you from plugging in an `int` inside an array of `Object`s.

Answer (score 4):

Ask yourself why you think it's strange that a type that is typically allocated on the stack would inherit from `System.Object` and I think you'll find you can't formulate a good reason.

If you think it's because an object's *type* defines where it is allocated, you're mistaken. What member of `ValueType` is responsible for defining its allocation mechanism? (What member of `System.Object`, for that matter?)

Type inheritance in .NET is supposed to comprise "**is a**" relationships: a `string` **is an** `object`, for example. *Everything* in the .NET world **is** an `object`, so an `int` is an `object`, a `double` is an `object`, etc.

You can think of this in terms of the [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle): if I write code that expects an `object`, I should be capable of dealing with *any* type that **is** an `object`—i.e., anything at all. My code should be equally comfortable with a `string`, an `int`, a `List<int>`, etc.

Also note that `object` guarantees certain members that all types have as a consequence of this: `GetType`, `ToString`, and `GetHashCode`.

Comment: -1 it is remarkably bad answer. it doesn't explain anything. Also, "is-a" relationship does NOT mean that it has to derive from the same class. Likewise, an "object" doesn't mean it has to derive from `System.Object` class. It may not derive from anything, yet still can be an object. The question why `ValueType` derives from `Object` basically is a question of *semantic*, or type category : value-type vs reference-type.

Comment: @Nawaz Not true. Pointers don't derive from Object, thus they aren't objects.

Comment: It is a famous C# myth that value types are typically allocated on stack.

Comment: @RBT: Are they not allocated on the stack?

Comment: No. *Most* of the times value types go to heap only. Only when they are local variables inside a method is when they will be allocated on stack. Please have look at [this](http://jonskeet.uk/csharp/memory.html) famous blog from Jon Skeet which will make thing crystal clear for you from all aspects.