# C# - Why convert a type to object works like this?

Tags: c#, oop, type-conversion

I'm trying to understand:

```
Object obj = "string";
var type = obj.GetType(); // returns System.String
```

I know this is a successful implicit conversion but I don't understand why if  `obj.GetType()` is called it returns `System.String` and not `System.Object`.

If i'd want to have a string type, I would not have assigned "string" to an `Object` type. It would be more correct if `obj` will remain a `Object` type. Can anyone explain?

Comment: `GetType()` returns the runtime type of the object, which is always `string` from start to finish. If you want to get the type of the variable, just hover over it and write `typeof(object)` (or whatever you want). [Each one has its use](http://stackoverflow.com/a/983061/1892179).

Comment: Also you may want to read on https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+convert+vs+cast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a `string` literal and its type is `string`. When you assign it to `obj` variable which is an `object`, `string` literal is implicitly converted to `object`, this is valid because all class types implicitly inherits from `object`.

So you have an `object` but the underlying type of the object that `obj` is referring to is still `string`. By converting it to `object`you are only making it so that compiler will treat `obj` as `object`, not `string`. Because of this, for example you can't call methods declared on `string` type using `obj`.

`obj.GetType()` returns the underlying type, not the type you converted your object into. That is why you are getting `string` and not `object`.

Comment: "When you assign it to obj variable which is an object, string literal is implicitly converted to object". That is not true, the string literal isn't converted to anything. The reference is.

Answer (score 0):

Because its a *reference conversion*. As the name implies, in a reference conversion, the only thing that changes is the *reference*, AKA the variable pointing to the object.

The bits that make up the string literal `"string"` *don't change*, the only thing you are doing in `Object o = "string"` is creating a variable `o` typed `Object` that *points* to the the `string` `"string"`. The value stored in the variable `o` is precisely the address in memory where that `string` is:

Given:

```
var s = "Hello";
```

Any of these conversions are reference conversions:

```
object o = s; //creates a new reference typed object pointing to "Hello".
IComparable<string> e = s; //creates a new reference tpyed...
```

`o.GetType()` and `e.GetType()` will both return `System.String` because `o` and `e` both point to exactly the same object: `"Hello"`.

Now this isn't the only conversion that can happen. There are tons of conversions that are not reference conversions or identity preserving conversions. An example? All  user defined conversions (`implicit` or `explicit` operator):

```
int i = 1;
double d = i;
d.GetType() //returns Double.
```

Why? Because `i` and `d` are two different objects, the bits that make up an integer and a double are completely different. The implicit cast from `int` to `double` is a user defined operator:

```
class Bar
{
    public Bar(Foo f) { ... }
}

class Foo
{
    public static implicit operator Bar(Foo f) => new Bar(f);
}
```

Now if you do:

```
var f = new Foo();
object o = f;
Bar b = f; //implicit user defined conversion from Foo to Bar
```

You will get the following outputs:

```
o.GetType() //Reference conversion: returns Foo
b.GetType() //User defined conversion: returns Bar
```

Do note that *all* reference conversions are provided by the compiler, you can't *define* a reference conversion as a user defined operator:

```
public static implicit operator Object(Foo f) { ... } //compile time error.
```

All that said, there is one special non identity preserving conversion where `GetType()` will still return the type of the original object. Can you tell me which one it is?

Also, reference conversions involving value types are not possible, precisely because a value type variable's value is not a reference, it's the value type instance itself.

Answer (score -1):

Actually, as everything in C# inherits from `object`, everything *is* an object. For example the `string` type derives from object (Take a look at this for more information: [Value types inherit from System.Object...why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4729094/value-types-inherit-from-system-object-why)). That means, every string *is* an object - and can therefore implicitly be converted to an object. However, it still remains a string - it is just treated as an object.

The string actually remains in it's core still a string, even if you try to cast it to an object - this is the same for every inheriting item. For example, if you have the following code:

```
public class Class2 : Class1
{

}

public class Class1
{

}
```

And execute the following code somewhere else (I used the *interactive*)

```
((Class1)new Class2()).GetType()
```

You'd still get `Class2` as a result.

Actually, I don't think it's possible to do so - you can always *pretend* that it is of another type, and I don't see any reason why this shouldn't be sufficient.

Comment: `string` is not a value type though.