# add properties to an object of type object

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
object o = new { foo = 1 };
```

Is there any other way to add properties to the object?

Neither `o["foo"] = 1` nor `o.foo = 1` seems to be working.

And if i type

```
var o = new { foo = 1 };
```

Why is the type of `var` an "AnonomuysType" and not `object`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just add properties to compiled types. The only time that will work *as properties* (well, kind-of) is if you are using the `dynamic` API, and the object is something that *supports* dynamic properties, for example:

```
dynamic obj = new ExpandoObject();
obj.Foo = 123;
obj.Bar = "abc";
```

however, those values are not available via reflection. An easier approach may be something that behaves as a dictionary:

```
var obj = new Dictionary<string,object>();
obj["Foo"] = 123;
obj["Bar"] = "abc";
```

there are more discoverable, via the dictionary API. Re your final question: when you do:

```
var o = new { foo = 1 };
```

the `new { foo = 1 }` causes the compiler to generate an *anonymous type*, which is a regular C# class with read-only properties and an unpronounceable name. This can be referred to as `object` (it is a regular `class`, after all), but when you use `var` the compiler uses the known type (with the horrible name), which gives you access to the properties (`.foo` in this case).

Comment: I see. Would the `JavaScriptSerializer` have any problems serializing an object of the `dynamic` type?

Comment: @John yes, it would; dictionary would be better for that

Answer (score 1):

All *objects* inherit from `Object` even an anonymous type(see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436211/is-everything-in-net-an-object)). You can see that here:

```
object o = new { foo = 1 };
if (o is object)
    Console.Write("Yes, i'm an object!");
else 
    Console.Write("no, no, i'm not an object!");
```

You cannot add properties to an anonymous type, only when you you create it.

You could use a `Dictionary<string, object>` instead:

```
var o = new Dictionary<string, object>();
o.Add("Foo", 123);
o.Add("Bar", "abc");
```

Now you can access them in this way:

```
object bar = o["Bar"]; // "abc"
```