# Is boxing involved when calling ToString for integer types?

Tags: c#, .net, boxing

Very simple question:

```
int a = 5;
string str = a.ToString();
```

Since `ToString` is a virtual method of System.Object, does it mean that everytime I call this method for integer types, a boxing occurs?

Comment: [C# Boxing DataTypes](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_data_types.htm)
[MSDN Boxing and UnBoxing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You've already got answers telling you that when `ToString()` is overridden for a value type, there will be no boxing when you call it, but it's nice to have some way of actually seeing that.

Take the type `int?` (`Nullable<int>`). This is a useful type because it is a value type, yet boxing may produce a null reference, and instance methods cannot be called through a null reference. It does have an overridden `ToString()` method. It does not have (and cannot have) an overridden `GetType()` method.

```
int? i = null;
var s = i.ToString(); // okay: initialises s to ""
var t = i.GetType(); // not okay: throws NullReferenceException
```

This shows that there is no boxing in the call `i.ToString()`, but there is boxing in the call `i.GetType()`.

Answer (score 7):

The other answers mention that the `ToString` call will not result in boxing.  It's worth noting a corollary:

```
int i = 42;
String.Format("number: {0}", i.ToString());
```

will not result in boxing, whereas:

```
int i = 42;
String.Format("number: {0}", i);
```

will.

(You hear that, Resharper?)

(However, bear in mind that if you're applying a formatter to `String.Format` (e.g. `CultureInfo`, you need to use the second version)

Answer (score 4):

No, boxing does not occur. When virtual method is called, CLR looks for type object pointer to get actual overrriden method from method table. For value types there is no object pointer, so direct non-virtual call is made instead, JIT knows that there are no polimorphic side-effects because value types are sealed. However, boxing might occur if `ToString()` of value type calls `base.ToString()`: then actual instance is  boxed and passed to `System.ValueType.ToString()` 
`Int32.ToString()` does not call `base.ToString()` and use native implemenation, hence no boxing occur.

Answer (score 3):

When you decompile the `Int32.ToString()` call you can see it implements `FormatInt32` which is native C++ methods. The method is implemented as follows:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return Number.FormatInt32(
    this,
    null,
    NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo);
}

[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
public static extern string FormatInt32(
    int value,
    string format,
    NumberFormatInfo info);
```

Which calls `Int32ToDecChars`:

```
wchar_t* COMNumber::Int32ToDecChars(
wchar_t* p,
unsigned int value,
int digits)
{
    LEAF_CONTRACT
    _ASSERTE(p != NULL);

    while (--digits >= 0 || value != 0) {
        *--p = value % 10 + '0';
        value /= 10;
    }
    return p;
}
```

It takes each digit, converts to a separate `char` and stores in a string. The string is then returned. So there is no boxing of `int` involved.

Under this link you can find fairly thorough explanation of what actually happens when invoking `ToString()` on an `int`. As a bonus the article also explains all the mechanisms behind `Int32.Parse()`:

https://selvasamuel.wordpress.com/2008/03/14/boxingunboxing-in-net/

Comment: This doesn't show whether there's any boxing. All it shows is that if there is boxing, there is also later unboxing, but that isn't surprising.

Comment: The int is converted to char - another value type. And then string is constracted from char.

Comment: What I'm trying to say is this doesn't eliminate the possibility of it having been converted to `object` first, and back to `int` prior to that method being called.

Answer (score 2):

Since `ToString` is overriden in `Int32` class - no, there will no boxing in this case as no instance on `object` will be created.

Simply appropriate method of Int32 is called because of dynamic dispatch.

Answer (score -5):

It depends on how the ToString() function implemented in Int32 class. Since the implementation done by .net framework, we can't confirm whether boxing happens or not.