# Is there a difference if I convert string to int or int to string?

Tags: c#, string, type-conversion, int

I am working on a C# project and I simply need to enter a numeric value into a textfield of an application within a method.

The EnterText() method that enters the value into the textbox only takes string values.

Is there a difference between:

```
EnterValue("100")
public void EnterValue(string value)
{
     myTextField.EnterText(value);
}
```

and

```
EnterValue(100);
public void EnterValue(int value)
{
    myTextField.EnterText(value.ToString());
}
```

?

I couldn't really find anything and I am wondering if one option is better than the other and why.

Comment: what is `myTextField` ?

Comment: If you want to make sure that Text passed to `EnterText` is valid integer, than second approach is better.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey That is not boxing.  Boxing would be `var o = (object)100;`.  That's formatting an integer to a string.

Comment: @juharr - I missed that he is calling the method as an int. The code in the question is odd.  However, if he is in fact dealing with a textbox in reality as he said then yes he has to deal with unboxing.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey There's no boxing or unboxing needed.  If the OP needs to convert from `int` to `string` that's formatting.  From `string` to `int` is parsing.  Boxing only occurs if you cast a value type to a reference type and there is no cast between `string` and `int`.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey if you call this code example odd, how would your solution look like? I always try to learn more.

Comment: Well, I just found out that `ToString` is overridden for value types so no boxing occurs.  That's a special case and makes it difficult to get at what I *think* the jist of your question is getting to.  Essentially value types and reference types and boxing and unboxing.  Lots of info on SO about this.  However, the question just happen to hit an exceptional case in C#.  Not really your fault, I had no idea either and I've been coding C# a long time.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey `ToString` doesn't involve boxing even when it's not overriden.  The default is to return the name of the type.

Comment: @juharr - I don't think we are speaking the same language.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27132042/is-boxing-involved-when-calling-tostring-for-integer-types

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey What I specifically mean is that `ToString` will never produce a boxed value.  It is possible that boxing occurs during the call depending on implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I consider your case, first sample is much more better because of, you do not need to convert operation. However, If you want to `myTextField` contains only digit value, second option is better.

Different case require different code design, hence; please give more spesification.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and help. As I am not a experienced programmer at all I do not always think about these aspects. It is important that it only contains digit values so I go for the second option.