# Why doesn't class System.Object is not present in the parent classes list in the definition of Int32 class?

Tags: c#, .net

Here is a screenshot of the code definition from metadata:

[image]

And no one can deny the fact that all types inherit from `Object` class, but that is not the case in the definition of the `Int32` class (and other classes BTW)
I know that VS is smarter than me, but I want to know how it can keep Object class as a parent if it is not present in the definition?

Comment: *no one can deny the fact that all types inherit from Object* - I deny it! `int`/`Int32` is a [`struct`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ah19swz4.aspx), not a `class`.

Comment: from where then it implements the methods: CompareTo(), ToString()..?

Comment: [What's the difference between struct and class in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13049/whats-the-difference-between-struct-and-class-in-net)

Comment: @FedericoDipuma - `structs` inherit `System.ValueType` which inherits `System.Object`.

Comment: Thanks, that's new to my knowledge

Comment: @Lee of course you are right, I was emphasizing the fact that from a *code point of view* the inheritance is implicit and not evident.

Comment: what about string class?

Answer (score 0):

There’s even more interesting question: if `Object` is a class, hence a reference type, and all types in C# inherit from `Object`, how would some of them be value types then?

The answer is that not all types derive from `Object` explicitly. There’s reference types and value types. Value types implicitly inherit from the `ValueType` class (which is ‘class’ so should be a reference type but as we know all value types are not reference types which is pretty logically).

There’s a more deep separation of value and reference types so you can’t see them by going to the metadata. You can read more on this topic here: [Is everything in .NET an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436211/is-everything-in-net-an-object/436246)