# C# - Make a new class not part of System.Object

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have a huge code base and I recently made a change where I changed the type of a parameter from `String` to a custom class. On the next compile I got all the areas where the impact was, but areas where the input type was of type `Object` failed. for e.g.

```
String str = "32"
int i = Convert.ToInt32(str)
```

Now I have changed `String` to a new custom type lets say `MyCustomClass` I would now want following code to fail on next compile

```
MyCustomClass str = new MyCustomClass("32")
int i = Convert.ToInt32(str)
```

but it won't as `Convert.ToInt32` also accepts type `Object`. Is there some way I can make a change in `MyCustomClass` that it's not considered `Object` anymore.
**Please note**: `Convert.ToInt32` is only used for sample I have many more such functions, so please focus your suggestion/answer to question asked.

Comment: every type derives from object, you can't change that. the question is why you have methods that take object as parameter ? why not using type safe methods? or generics etc. ?

Comment: nearly a duplicate question of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/436211/is-everything-in-net-an-object

Comment: @KrikorAilanjian, Convert.ToInt32 is not his code.  Can't refactor the base class libraries

Comment: @KrikorAilanjian That's not possible as all of that code is third party or framework level.

Comment: @BuhBuh my bad I misinterpreted what was being asked, I knew that `Convert.ToInt32` is not his code :)

Comment: @user961954 Do you want to fail so you can fix all of the references, or do you actually want the int32 conversion to work?

Comment: @johnny5 I just want it to fail so I can fix it. In any case it will fail in runtime but that will be too late as that would most likely be in production. I want to catch all of them in development.

Comment: So you're end goal isn't really to find all the places where you need to change it, your end goal is to have a solution in which, Your Int32 Conversion won't fail

Comment: @johnny5 my end goal is to find all the places where I need to change it.

Comment: @user961954, so you're saying you would not accept a solution that fixed your problem with out having to change all of those references?

Comment: @user961954 What do you intend to do with this line: `int i = Convert.ToInt32(str)`.   Would you delete it?  Replace it with `MyCustomClassConverter.ToInt32` ?

Comment: @BuhBuh Once it fails during compile, I will know that I have to make a change here and I will let's say change it to `str.GetString()` where `str` is of type `MyCustomClass`

Comment: Awesome, I think I have an answer. (half answer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Override `ToString()` and `IConvertible`

You said in the comments that your intentions are to find places where your object, which had previously been treated as a string, and are now being treated as an object.

In these situations typically, the third-party code would call `.ToString()` on your object to get something which it can use.
So, `Convert.ToInt32(str)` is equivalent to `Convert.ToInt32(str.ToString())`.

**If you implement ToString() and IConvertible to return whatever your old version of `str` looked like** then it should continue to work in the same way as the old version.

Probably.

Sorry I know that is not the 100% perfect compile time answer you were looking for, but I think you also know very well that your `MyCustomClass` will always be considered object.

Comment: [`Convert.ToInt32(object)`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/convert.cs,1024) calls `((IConvertible)value).ToInt32(null)` so you should implement `IConvertible` instead.

Comment: @Lee That kind of killed my flow.  But ok great, thanks I've added that in!

Comment: I think what I truly want is not achievable and as this comes closest to my solution I will accept this as answer.

Answer (score 1):

Possible compile time answer:

- Write a tool which uses reflection to iterate over every class/struct/interface in every system/third-party DLL.
- Output a load of CS files which contain all these same classes, but just throw NotImplementedException.
  (T4 could help you do this)
- Compile these classes into dummy.dll
- Your .csproj now references only this one dummy.dll, instead of the real dlls.
  Your project should compile fine against the dummy dll.
- Look at your dummy.cs files and delete any use of object.
- Re-compile... and suddenly you get a load of compile time errors showing you anywhere you are using an object.

Answer (score 1):

Impliment an *implicit cast* from MyCustomClass to String.

```
public static implicit operator string(MyCustomClass str)
{
    return "Legacy respresentation of str";
}
```

This allows the complier the choice of choosing ToInt32(Object) or ToInt32(String), and I bet it favours the later.

This way all your existing function calls will remain the same so you wont have to be concerned about third party implentation details.

(Sorry, I am not at a computer right now so I can`t test that my assumtion is correct.  If you do test this, be sure to consider extension methods, as they can affect the conpilers desision making in unexpected ways)